# PouchDB Full Text Search

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, pouchdb

Question for the PouchDB community. I'm thinking of using PouchDB but I need full text search as well - I see that [pouchdb-quick-search](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-quick-search) exists but it and other community projects seem to be fairly dormant.

Is pouchdb-quick-search currently a viable and supported option for full text search with PouchDB?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/cyphercider/pouchdb-quick-search updated the code only 3 weeks ago.. so there are some active development happening. Of course as seems to be the case with many pouchdb plugins - they can be very dormant :(